# scala macro for conversion of structtype to case class

Tags: scala, generics, macros, case-class

How could I define a scala macro which converts a spark structtype of i.e.

```
val foo = new StructType ()
    .add ("foo", LongType)
    .add ("bar", LongType)
```

to a case class of:

```
MyCaseClass(foo:Long, bar:Long)
```

## edit

```
trait Schema {
    def schema: Seq[MyCol]
  }

  case class MyCol(name: String, colType: AbstractDataType, nullabilty: Boolean)

  case class FooSchema() extends Schema {
    override def schema: Seq[MyCol] = Seq(MyCol("foo", IntegerType, false), MyCol("bar", DoubleType, false))
  }
```

Comment: The `StructType` seems to be defined a runtime ...

Comment: Would it help if I use a case class in the layout of a structtype as the input?

Comment: A macro can hardly generate static types for structures defined by method invocation.

Comment: Even if specified like: `StructType(Seq(StructField("foo", FloatType), StructField("bar", FloatType)))`?

Comment: That's still invocation

Comment: Please see the edit. How would it work when I define my own custom statically typed schema?

Comment: your schema is not statically defined

Comment: But it should be possible iterate the AST and create a new attribute for each column name? If macros are not the right tool - is there another approach?

Comment: with such schema, at runtime, but not at compile time, so no benefit for macro

Comment: How could I define the schema to work with macros? If not possible, what else could lead to the desired outcome?

Comment: use a static type/representation as base to generate other representation, rather than starting from a dynamic/runtime one

Comment: Can you link me an example?

Comment: you can find plenty of example of type derivation using macro based on case classes and sealed trait